# Impossible to modify the return value of 'Selectable.Colors' because it's not a variable

Tags: c#

There are many questions like mine, ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336665/cannot-modify-the-return-value-of-dictionary-because-it-is-not-a-variable), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126289/cannot-modify-the-return-value-because-it-is-not-a-variable), [d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549720/cannot-modify-the-return-value-of), [e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063694/cannot-modify-the-return-value-of-control-location-because-it-is-not-a-variabl) and [f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp)) but no one answers correctly... This code works:

```
ColorBlock c = ButtonLeft.colors;
c.normalColor = LeftNormal;
c.highlightedColor = LeftPressed;
```

If I want to avoid variable I try this:

```
ButtonLeft.colors.normalColor = LeftNormal;
ButtonLeft.colors.highlightedColor = LeftPressed;
```

But it doesnt work with the error:

"`Impossible to modify the return value of 'Selectable.Colors' because it's not a variable.`"

What does this mean? And why cant I do this? And the next question is never answered: **when should I know my code wont work and I'll need to use a variable**?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the error is that `ColorBlock` is a `struct`, i.e. a *value type*.

When you access `colors` property of `ButtonLeft`, a copy of the `struct` is made, i.e. `ButtonLeft.colors` is a copy of `ColorBlock` inside `ButtonLeft`. Although assignments to properties of `colors` could theoretically succeed, they would have no effect on the `colors` inside `ButtonLeft`, which is certainly a programming error. That is why the language triggers an error, prohibiting the assignment.

That is why you need to use `ClolrBlock` in the way described by the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock-normalColor.html):

```
ColorBlock cb = ButtonLeft.colors;
cb.normalColor = newColor;
button.colors = cb;
```

Comment: Ok, but why do C# make a copy of the struct instead of giving me a pointer to that struct? And thus what does `ColorBlock cb = ButtonLeft.colors;` exactly do? Allocate memory and copy/paste the values? Create a new pointer to that struct?

Comment: @OlivierPons C# makes a copy of `struct` because unlike `classes`, which are always returned as references, `struct`s are always copied. If API designers wanted to return you a pointer (a reference) they would make `ColorBlock` a `class`.